# Page not found when reloading Angular page on Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I've deployed my angular app to firebase. I can see the sign in page fine but I get the following error when I reload the page:

```
This file does not exist and there was no index.html found in the current directory or 404.html in the root directory.

Why am I seeing this?

You may have deployed the wrong directory for your application. Check your firebase.json and make sure the public directory is pointing to a directory that contains an index.html file.
You can also add a 404.html in the root of your site to replace this page with a custom error page.
```

So as the error suggests I checked my `firebase.json` file and it displays this:

```
{
  "firebase": "******",
  "public": "dist",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

Here you can see that my `public` folder is my `dist` folder. This `dist` folder is actually where I place all of my files (css,js,html and the index.html) when gulp builds it all. The folder structure looks like this:

```
dist
  css
  images
  js
  templates
  index.html
```

So the destination folder above does have an `index.html` page - so why am I getting this error? Angular should be stepping in here and handling all routing but that doesn't seem to be the case.

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: Nothing here suggests a solution to your problem. Something else must be at play. Can you try --debug in your deploy and see exactly which files are being uploaded and which are being skipped?

Comment: @Kato I know I asked this last week but do you have any other thoughts on what's happening here?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I fixed the problem - this problem is caused by Firebase (indeed all servers I think) believing that each Angular state is a folder which should contain its own `index.html` file - obviously this isn't the case.

What needs to happen is for it to only refer to our `index.html` in the root of the folder. To do that you need to modify your `firebase.json` file to the following:

```
{
  "firebase": "app-name",
  "public": "dist",
  "ignore": [
    "firebase.json",
    "**/.*",
    "**/node_modules/**"
  ],
  "rewrites": [{
    "source": "/public/**",
    "destination": "/public.html"
  },
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }]
}
```

The important parts here are the rewrites and the source objects. Refer to the `firebase.json` explanation page for more info on this: [firebase.json](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/url-redirects-rewrites)

Comment: You save my day :)

Comment: @calistus no problem

Answer (score 8):

2018 and had the samed problem. Katana24 gave a good answer but since then, firebase updated a bit. Here is the Katana24 answer updated :

**firebase.json:**

```
{
"functions": {
    "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
},
"hosting": {
    "public": "dist/YOURAPPNAME",
    "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [{
            "source": "/public/**",
            "destination": "/public.html"
        },
        {
            "source": "**",
            "destination": "/index.html"
        }
    ],
    "storage": {
        "rules": "storage.rules"
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use [firebase-tools](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase-tools) you can hit **y** (yes) at the question:

**Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)?**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

in `firebase.json`, `hosting` section add the `rewrites`

```
"rewrites": [ {
  "source": "**",
  "destination": "/index.html"
} ],
```

[image]